# ASP.NET Core MVC5 - Redirect to the same section in the view after finishing the action?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC in VS2019 community.

My view is so long so I divided it into sections, every link in navbar will lead the user to specific section. The last section called [contact], this section user will add his data and message then click [send]. after clicking button I want to stay in the same place without going any further because I will view a span with the result of his action to thank him for contacting us.

I used this code:

```
    // POST: CompController/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(MInbox newRecord)
    {
        string currentSection = "/#contact";
        TempData["Result"] = "0";
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                OperSucceeded = repo_Inbox.Add(newRecord);

                if (OperSucceeded == 1)
                {
                    TempData["Result"] = "1";
                    return RedirectPreserveMethod(currentSection);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction(currentSection);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Result"] = "2";
            return RedirectToAction(currentSection);
        }
    }
```

This work god but the page reload then come down to section [contact], I hope to prevent reloading.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent reloading and view a span with the result of his action to thank him for contacting us. I suggest you use ajax to achieve your requirement.

Here is a simple demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class MInbox 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MInbox 

<h1>Create</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" onclick="Create()" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<span id="response"></span>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function Create() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                url: "/Comp/Create",
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res) {
                        $("#response").text("Thank you for contacting us!");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#response").text("error");
                    }
                }  
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MInbox item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do your stuff...
        return Json(true);
    }
    return Json(false);
}
```

Comment: thanks Rena, your code helped me and worked fine.